# Mongoose validate and save code

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

That is how I validating and saving my user:

```
var user = new User({ /** from body **/ });

user.validate((err) => {
      if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid input' });
       }
       else {
             user.save((err) => {
                if (err) { throw err; }
                console.log(err);
                res.json({ success: true });
            });
       }
  });
```

Is there a better way of validate and save with mongoose with the less code lines or without `if/else`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also add your validations inside your schema. I will recommend this way because you'll be able to make custom validations depending of the field.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Then you'll only need to save your user and check for an error inside the save callback method.

Comment: Beware, beware: If one misuses the handy prop [`collection`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-collection) on a given [`Model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) and blindly calls `MyModel.collection.insert(documentOrPlainJSON)`, the validations given in `MyModel`'s `schema` **won't run**. One should use `MyModel.create(props)` or `new MyModel(props).save()`